# ArcSDE Enterprise Geodatabase - XML and Tolerance Issue

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, xml

I set up an ArcSDE Enterprise Geodatabase in SQL Server 2012. I imported the XML file from the Utility and Pipeline Data Model without any modifications. I am now running into an issue: the XY tolerance is set at 0.0002 degrees in the XML and when I go to digitize a polyline it is not saving it properly. I have the feature class and data frame set to WGS_1984 and the XY tolerance does not change. Any suggestions on how to fix?[image: digitize issue screen capture]

Comment: 0.0002 degrees is quite coarse -- ~22 meters

Comment: I have a feeling the data model was originally set up with a projected coordinate system which would make more sense with the 0.0002 tolerance value. Create a fc using WGS84 to get the values for the xy resolution, tolerance, AND domain that you'll need to update in the xml file.